# Can an XSS exploit on a subdomain steal the cookies of the parent domain?

Tags: web-application, xss, cookies

As per my understanding, if a cookie doesn't have a domain attribute (explicitly telling where this cookie can be used), by default that cookie will be used by the domain which issued it and all its subdomain, but the parent domain of the domain which issued the cookie can't use it.

So if `foo.example` issued a cookie, it can be used by the subdomain `bar.foo.example.com` but not it's parent domain i.e. `example.com`.

Now, suppose I found an XSS vulnerability on `foo.example.com` and I want to get the cookies of `example.com`. By any means is that possible? Since by default cookies issued by a subdomain can not be used by it's parent domain, I am not able to figure out any way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Comment: The link you shared talks about cookies which I already know, am trying to understand if XSS is possible this way.

Answer (score 1):

A subdomain can only share a cookie with its parent domain if it is explicitly given in the set-cookie header issued by the server like this:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=www.parentdomain.com
```

Otherwise the cookie is "host only cookie"

To answer your question an xss should not be possible
Or i am wrong